# What is the best practice for email handling in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hello guys I'm developing the e-commence application in CakePHP 3 ,now I have to write the emails for sending the order status to the site administrator and the users so I was wondering that I should place my all emails function in one file and call them according to the requirement in different controllers.As I'm new in CakePHP so I would like to know the best way ,where should I write all these emails function in the application.Should I write different controller,modal or component.

Comment: Read the manual: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-reusable-emails

Answer (score 0):

Hello Aman I've developed a file with all the functions for sending e-mails, I sugest you to create a component or a behaviour. A component if you just would like to send e-mails by your controllers, and a behaviour if you would like to create jobs/cronjobs to send e-mails by a task, then if you create a behaviour you can use it in TasksShell, Models and Controllers, its much more flexible.

Comment: Can we call functions inside behaviour directly from the controller without creating the model?

Comment: I don't think so, I guess you must create one model because when you call functions from a behaviour inside a controller you call like, this functions belongs to model instead behaviour

Comment: avaliable for any other doubt ;) try and tell me if its works

Comment: This is just wrong. Use the mailer functionality CakePHP provides out of the box. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-reusable-emails

Comment: This is not wrong if you create a behavior and functions that extend cakephp email functions. In my case a developed a file that allows me to manage emails delivered, if module of notifications is enabled or not and many other funciona that cake don't do. So I extend it. It's not wrong is entirely right

Comment: They should not extend but use composition. The custom mailers provide a way to exactly do that and are built into the CakePHP framework.

Comment: For me that works how I wanted, and better than cake provide